# local server can't send message to Android application due to Proxy- GCM

Tags: android, proxy, google-cloud-messaging

I try to implement GCM from http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html

I can't send message to application. 
I added System.setProperty... to servlet and http.proxyHost=proxy.company.com  http.proxyPort=8080 to catalina.properties from this page [Google cloud messaging GCM through proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444372/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-through-proxy)

Servlet:
    Sender sender = new Sender(myApiKey);

```
                Message message = new Message.Builder()
                .collapseKey("1")
                .timeToLive(3)
                .delayWhileIdle(true)
                .addData("message", "message is created at builder")
                .build();

                System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "10.200.125.200");  
                System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080"); 

                Result result = sender.send(message, reGid, 5);
                System.out.println("result of message is "+ result);
```

GCMIntentService.java:

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
Log.i(TAG, "new message= ");
Toast.makeText(this, arg1.getStringExtra("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

sender.send doesn't work, i think proxy block it.
console:

```
 A?u 09, 2012 10:55:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke SEVERE:  Servlet.service() for servlet [servCloud] in context with path [/servletCloud] threw   exception
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at     java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:612)
at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:160)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:378)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:473)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:270)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:327)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:199)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:950)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1090)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.post(Sender.java:476)
at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.post(Sender.java:455)
at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Sender.java:170)
at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.send(Sender.java:121)
at servCloud.doGet(servCloud.java:85)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

How can i set sender.send or get over proxy?

Answer (score 2):

GCM endpoint server uses HTTPS.
You can try the following system properties:

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "10.200.125.200");  
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8080");
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issues and the System.setProperty mentinoed here not helped.

I created below class and refactor the code to use ProxySender instead of Sender class and it works finally.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.URL;

import com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender;

public class ProxySender extends Sender {

    public ProxySender(String key) {
        super(key);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected HttpURLConnection getConnection(String url) throws IOException {

        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("1.2.3.4.", 8080));

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection(proxy);

        return conn;

    }
}
```

remember modify the proxy server and port.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution. Worked flawlessly for me. Instead of the IP address , we can also send the host-name there, it works.