# Can GCM works through proxy?

Tags: android, proxy, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to work GCM through proxy . I don't find any way to give my proxy details in the GCM server docs.

I tried to set the System.setProperty as described in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444372/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-through-proxy).  But it is not working for me.

The only way i can able to work it by modifying the gcm-server code.  [ Included proxy details in Post() method. ]

I am not sure about the license is allowed to modify the GCM server source and use it for commercial purpose.

Please let me know is this possible?

Comment: Please refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444372/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-through-proxy) may be it will help you